# Clarification on "what if _ happened?" off-topic questions

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Many (all?) Stack Exchange sites include an off-topic question category that reads:

> you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”

I read this as referring specifically to questions that set up a hypothetical scenario, but don't ask about any specific *result* from that scenario, as opposed to referring to hypothetical questions in general.

(1) "What sort of results would result if _?" fits this bill.

(2) "Suppose that _.  In this scenario would _ result?" does not fit this bill.  Although it sets up a hypothetical scenario, it is not open-ended, since it asks about one specific result.

Is this a correct reading of this rule?

Comment: Of course, option (2) may run afoul of other off-topicnesses, but it doesn't seem to me that it violates this one.

Comment: Most sites want practical, concrete problems their asker's are experiencing. If you only have a hypothetical, then chances are good there are not enough details to properly answer it in the first place.

Comment: An easy example of open-ended, hypothetical question (and also Primarily Opinion-Based) from Anime.SE: "Goku vs. Luffy, who would win?" While this is a fun question to ponder, unless this really happens in official works, *everything could happen depending on the poster's imagination* and nothing came useful from any of the answers. Pick one: Goku won, Luffy won, both tied. Every answer is too subjective and possible...

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. this is interesting... I guess "asks about one specific result" is insufficient to distinguish open-endedness or not.  I am more attuned to the science-y stack exchange sites where hypotheticals can be a necessity, but it's usually fine if your question is focused.  Probably the site that gets it the most is [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) where [hypothetical situations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/500833/gas-pipes-why-does-gas-burn-outwards) are almost a norm (nobody is actually experiencing a practical, concrete problem with a black hole).

Comment: @Scott note that some sites have an explicit policy about hypothetical questions, like [on Meta Physics.SE](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7614/why-cant-i-ask-hypothetical-questions), though you're probably mixing "hypothetical" with "theoretical".

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. in scientific parlance the difference between the two terms is nuanced.  Your linked question specifically asks about "questions about situations that **can't happen in the first place.**" [emphasis mine]  On the other hand many physics questions are "questions about situations that *could* happen, but not in any practical sense." [e.g.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26185/what-will-the-universe-look-like-for-anyone-falling-into-a-black-hole), and are therefore still, in some very real sense, hypothetical.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. But your link definitely shows that there is some odious type of question out there.  I'm simply trying to pinpoint what that exact quality is.